# Why TypeScript does not see the enums in libraries?

Tags: javascript, typescript, validation

Here is TypeScript types for [html-validator](https://www.npmjs.com/package/html-validator):

```
declare namespace HtmlValidator {

    // ...

    enum ValidationResultsOutputFormats {
        json = 'json',
        html = 'html',
        xhtml = 'xhtml',
        xml = 'xml',
        gnu = 'gnu',
        text = 'text'
    }

    interface OptionsForHtmlFileAsValidationTargetAndObjectAsResult extends OptionsForHtmlFileAsValidationTarget {
      format?: 'json';
    }

    interface OptionsForHtmlFileAsValidationTargetAndTextAsResults extends OptionsForHtmlFileAsValidationTarget {
      format: 'html' | 'xhtml' | 'xml' | 'gnu' | 'text';
    }

    interface OptionsForExternalUrlAsValidationTargetAndObjectAsResult extends OptionsForExternalUrlAsValidationTarget {
      format?: 'json';
    }

    interface OptionsForExternalUrlAsValidationTargetAndTextAsResults extends OptionsForHtmlFileAsValidationTarget {
      format: 'html' | 'xhtml' | 'xml' | 'gnu' | 'text';
    }
}
```

( [Full Version](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/html-validator/index.d.ts))

I want to use `ValidationResultsOutputFormats` instead of string literals.
Neither IDE nor TypeScript compiles casts alert/error for below code:

```
import validateHtml, { ValidationResultsOutputFormats } from 'html-validator';


export default abstract class HtmlValidator {

  public static validateHtml(compiledHtmlFile: Vinyl): void {

    // ...

    validateHtml({
      data: compiledHtmlFile.contents.toString(),
      format: ValidationResultsOutputFormats.json
    }).then((validationResults: validateHtml.ParsedJsonAsValidationResults) => 
    {
        // ...
    });
  }
}
```

However, because `ValidationResultsOutputFormats` is undefined, JavaScript error occurs.

```
Cannot read property 'json' of undefined
```

(refers to `format: ValidationResultsOutputFormats.json`).

It is some kind of mistake or TypeScript bug?

P. S. Please, not string literal solutions - it is a hardcoding.

### Update: my tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {

    "target": "es6",
    "strict": true,

    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,

    "lib": [
      "es2018"
    ],

    "baseUrl": "./",
    "paths": {}
  }
}
```

Comment: I don't think your aversion to string literals in necessarily justified, these are compile time checked strings, if a value is no longer valid for a function you will get a compile time error. With regard to `ValidationResultsOutputFormats`, are you sure it is defined in Javsacript ? I can't seem to find it in the code of the library you linked. If the enum is defined just in `.d.ts` it will not exist at runtime, definitions are supposed to reflect existing JS code not add new runtime behavior.

Comment: Could you update your question with the exact error you are getting? That way we can help better.

Comment: @AlejandroGarciaAnglada, I added the error message.

Answer (score 1):

Once you have installed the package `@types/html-validator` this way:

```
npm install @types/html-validator --dev
```

There is no need to import the type from the library itself.

Simply the namespace will be available to you in the global scope.

Try:

- Renaming your class so `HtmlValidator` don't get name clashed.
- Refer to `HtmlValidator` from the import.

```
import * as HtmlValidator from 'html-validator';


export default abstract class Validator {

  public static validateHtml(compiledHtmlFile: Vinyl): void {

    // ...

    validateHtml({
      data: compiledHtmlFile.contents.toString(),
      format: HtmlValidator.ValidationResultsOutputFormats.json
    }).then((validationResults: HtmlValidator.ParsedJsonAsValidationResults) => 
    {
        // ...
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer! There is the name clash... Are any other ways to avoid name clash by importing the namespace from global scope with other name?

Comment: Not really, I think you just need to be aware of what you are importing and try to not affect those names.

Comment: I tried your solution. Somehow, my TypeScript does not see the `HtmlValidator` namespace in global scope, so `HtmlValidator` causes error `TS2304: Cannot find name 'HtmlValidator'`.

Comment: Try adding `"types": ["html-validator"]` in your `tsconfig.json`

Comment: I am very sorry to say "It did not work"... Maybe I should to modify something in [type definitions](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/html-validator/index.d.ts)?

Comment: No, it should work straight away, maybe you are missing something in your tsconfig. Maybe `@types/node`? Could you update your answer with your tsconfig?

Comment: Sorry for the delay. I added my 'tsconfig.json' to answer. According documentation, all `@types` are included by default. There is also `@types/node` there.

Comment: Try getting HtmlValidator instead of from the global scope, from the import, updated my answer, check it out.